# ZeroCopyOutputStream into a streambuf

Tags: c++, streambuf

I would like to write a class that inherites from streambuf and adapts a [ZeroCopyOutputStream](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream.html#ZeroCopyOutputStream) (google/protobuf/io/) into a streambuf.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. write a proto description file and compile it to c++ code using protoc
2. the generated c++ class has functions to read/write to stream: SerializeToOstream(ostream* stream) and ParseFromIstream(istream* stream)

You may need to create iostream from streambuf by yourself.